# How to use scp URI with different port?

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to automate copying with `scp`.  If I use the default ssh port, the URI will look like:

```
scp://root@host:/root/ids/rules.tar.gz
```

But I changed my ssh port to `3131`.  How can I fetch and append the ssh port to the scp command?

Comment: checkout link if you have same problem. 

http://serverfault.com/questions/218256/specify-ssh-port-for-git

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beginning with version 7.7, The commonly-used `scp` command-line utility accepts URL as a command-line argument. The common way to specify a port number in a URL is following the hostname:

```
scp://root@host:3131/root/ids/rules.tar.gz
                ^^^^
```

Alternately, `scp` has a `-P` option to specify a port:

```
scp -P 3131 root@host:/root/ids/rules.tar.gz .
```

Comment: Worth noting, "scp://root@host:/..." should have a port "number" following the 'host:' and since it's missing, it uses the default of port 22 for ssh.  Without a port number, the ":" can be left off too for absolute paths(i.e. '...@host/path...'), but would be necessary on paths that don't start with '/' (i.e. '...@host:subdir/morepath...')

Answer (score 1):

You can use scp -P  to the command